# SimpleDateFormat Validation

Tags: java, mysql, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to validate date using Simple date format so that i can put it into MySQL database

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
sdf.setLenient(false);
java.util.Date testDate = sdf.parse("2011-13-05");
System.out.println(testDate);
```

Gives output,
Wed Jan 05 00:13:00 GMT-06:00 2011
Can anyone explain why the date is being converted into time and thus preventing detection of an invalid month 13? Does java.util.date have a date object rather than a datetime object?
A modified version of my code will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `MM` for month. `mm` is for [*minute in hour*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Didn't know that as a beginner.

Comment: @XperiazX. You're welcome :) But you should consider moving to *Joda Time* as suggested by JonSkeet in his answer. That's much better Date/Time API. And you get everything you want.

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain why the date is being converted into time and thus preventing detection of an invalid month 13?

Because your pattern specifies *minutes* rather than *months*. You want `MM` instead of `mm`. Whenever you have a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which isn't behaving as you expect it to, you should check your pattern against the documentation.

> Does java.util.date have a date object rather than a datetime object?

No, but [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) does (`LocalDate`). Joda Time is a *much* cleaner date/time API, which separates out different concepts helpfully:

- `Instant` (just a point in time - no time zone or calendar)
- `DateTime` (date and time with a time zone and calendar)
- `LocalDate` (just a date in a particular calendar)
- `LocalTime` (just a time of day in a particular calendar)
- `LocalDateTime` (date and time in a particular calendar)

There are some rough edges in terms of the API, but it's generally much better than `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. The [JSR-310 API](http://www.threeten.org/) which will be provided in Java 8 is different to both, but largely developed by one of the leaders of Joda Time, so there's a lot of conceptual overlap.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.But I'm doing a simple project and considered text validation and simple SQL insertion. Didn't want it to be too complex.